# Get helm release values (helm show values) via the Kubernetes Dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Is there a way to call `helm show values <chart_name>` via the Kubernetes Dashboard (web GUI)?

Comment: I do not think it's possible, there is no console or terminal in the standard dashboard.

Also to run this command you need to have helm installed somewhere and k8s configuration in place. In terms of Kubernetes, that means interactive session in an existing pod with certain version of helm, kubectl and proper config file.

You can use 3rd-party tool like [kubebox](https://github.com/astefanutti/kubebox) to open remote shell on running container - sometimes it's really useful.

Comment: NOTE: if you asked to get values via the dashboard, I assume you meant `helm get values <release-name>`. There are no charts in a cluster, there are helm releases - instances of charts. LMK if my guess is right - I will adjust the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in a way you asked. But I've used a `ConfigMap` trick for this:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: helm-release-{{ .Release.Name }}
data:
  Chart.yaml: |
{{ .Chart | toYaml | indent 4 }}
  values.yaml: |
{{ .Values | toYaml | indent 4 }}
```

Add this to your helm chart and it will show up on a Dashboard once you make a helm release. This `ConfigMap` is not used and does not affect anything, it's there just to debug easier.